# How to asynchronously run 3 processes, when one returns desired value stop the other two and continue with program?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method that uses the aforge.net framework to templatematch (check an image against another image for similarity) a number of seperate images against an area of the screen. This task can take a very long time or it can be near instant depending on the number of images, size of the images, and the area being checked.

Only 1 image in the list of images will ever return a match so I would like to test all the images against the screen at the same time and at which point 1 of these images returns true the remaining processes are immediately canceled and my program moves on to its next step.

Now, in the example I give I am grabbing an integer value based upon which match returns true but the concept is always the same.. x number of images tested against a screenshot.. 1 will return true, the rest will not.  Sometimes the first returns true and the process is nice and fast other times it's the 30th in the list and synchronously matching the template for 30 images takes a considerable amount of time in comparison to 1.

One caveat to note about my code that follows.. I won't always return an integer, I will normally return a boolean value as to which image was found but this code here was the easiest to detail and the same general principle applies (ie: if I can figure it out one way I'll be able to do it the other).

Currently my (synchronous) code reads as follows... How would I make this an asynchronous call that can do what I've described?  If possible please detail your answer as I intend to learn so that I can readily do this type of thing in the future. I understand the concept of async but for some reason cannot wrap my head around exactly how to do it the way I want.

```
    public void Battle()
    {
        var myGuysTurn = WhosTurn();

        // other logic here.
    }

    private int WhosTurn()
    {
        var whosTurn = 0;

        var whosTurnCheck = _templateMatch.Match(_tabula.BattleHeroTurn1());
        if (whosTurnCheck)
        {
            whosTurn = 1;
            return whosTurn;
        }

        whosTurnCheck = _templateMatch.Match(_tabula.BattleHeroTurn2());
        if (whosTurnCheck)
        {
            whosTurn = 2;
            return whosTurn;
        }

        whosTurnCheck = _templateMatch.Match(_tabula.BattleHeroTurn3());
        if (whosTurnCheck)
        {
            whosTurn = 3;
            return whosTurn;
        }

        return whosTurn;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `Task.WaitAny()` combined with a `CancellationToken`. Essentially, start each task in parallel and wait until any of complete. If the completed task was successful, cancel the others. If not, continue to wait for other tasks to complete.

I've replaced `_templateMatch.Match(_tabula.BattleHeroTurnX())` with a static method `BattleHeroTurnX` for brevity:

```
private int WhosTurn()
{
    // Create cancellation token. Will be used to inform other threads that they should immediately cancel processing
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Collection of tasks that run in parallel
    List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>()
    {
        Task.Run<int>(() => {
            return BattleHeroTurn1(cts.Token) ? 1 : 0; 
        }),
        Task.Run<int>(() => {
            return BattleHeroTurn2(cts.Token) ? 2 : 0;
        }),
        Task.Run<int>(() => {
            return BattleHeroTurn3(cts.Token) ? 3 : 0;
        })
    };

    // Wait for any task to complete and if it is successful, cancel the other tasks and return
    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        // Get the index of the task that completed
        int completedTaskIndex = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

        int turn = tasks[completedTaskIndex].Result;

        if(turn > 0)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            return turn;
        }

        tasks.RemoveAt(completedTaskIndex);
    }

    // All tasks have completed but no BattleHeroTurnX returned true
    return 0;
}

static bool BattleHeroTurn1(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Processing images. After each one is processed, ensure that the token has not been canceled
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

static bool BattleHeroTurn2(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Processing images. After each one is processed, ensure that the token has not been canceled
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(70);
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

static bool BattleHeroTurn3(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Processing images. After each one is processed, ensure that the token has not been canceled
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information.

Comment: Rather than constantly checking the token it's probably best to just use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Comment: Why are you creating an array each time you execute the `while` loop? Also, why block with `WaitAny`?

Comment: @Servy ThrowIfCancellationRequested would work here but he may have cleanup code to run if he is loading images. I also think that IsCancellationRequested is clearer for someone new to C# task cancellation.

Comment: @JasonFry Any cleanup code should be in a `finally` block regardless of the solution used, as the cleanup would need to be done even if an exception is thrown for any other reason.  `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is a fairly self-explanatory name.  If cancellation is requested, it throws.  Easy and clear, even for someone new to task cancellation.  It's all the *more* important to *do things right* when dealing with people new to cancellation.

Comment: @Servy Why is it wrong to use IsCancellationRequested?

Comment: @JasonFry It results in the task being marked as completed normally, not cancelled.  It also works regardless of the number of stack frames between the line of code and the top level of that operation, allowing it to cascade up instead of requiring checks at every single stack frame.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Instead of WaitAny what would you suggest? I have to create an array each time because I need to discard the completed task. I suppose I could instead discard the List and use an array with some sort of .Except().ToArray() business.

Comment: So I tested this in a simple Console Application with code included to write to textbox which BattleHeroTurn finishes first... (when BattleHeroTurn1 it writes 1 to console, etc for BattleHeroTurn2 and BattleHeroTurn3).  I altered the sleep timers so that 2 would finish first, followed by 1, then 3. Task 2 would finish 6 times before 1, than 1 would finish 1 time before 3 (which makes sense due to the sleep timers) but shouldn't the whole process cancel after 1 task completes? Furthermore the same task shouldn't complete multiple times should it?

Comment: @Fama_Sicura As the code is written above, task 2 will finish first, canceling tasks 1 and 3. If you instead return false in BattleHeroTurn2, task 2 will still finish first but will not cancel the other tasks. Task 1 will then complete and cancel task 3. I'm not seeing tasks complete multiple times, can you show me the modifications that you made to the sleep timers?

Comment: I wasn't paying attention to the for loop you'd written.  At first glance I thought you were determining when to cancel based upon the sleep timers but I see now that it is the loop.  I thought the loops all read 100.  This makes sense now.

Comment: @Fama_Sicura Excellent! The fact that you didn't just copy/paste the above, instead actually committing yourself to learning made my day.